# Function two plots in a 1*2 array

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want a function to return 2 charts side by side:

```
GraficosKMeans <- function(dados){ 
  g1 <- ggplot(dados, aes(x = cluster, y = ValorMedio))+
    geom_col()

  g2 <- ggplot(dados, aes(x = cluster, y = FrequenciaMedia))+
    geom_col()
  
  par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  # also tried layout(matrix(c(1,2), 1, 2))

  return(list(g1, g2))
 # also tried g1
 # also tried g2


}
```

Calling this function with:

```
GraficosKMeans(dados)
```

Is returing the charts separately. Why is the plotting area not set into a 1*2 array?

Comment: Where is `dados`? Please `dput(dados)` and add to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I've just edited my question above

Comment: Is `dados` a list or dataframe? The output you added looks incomplete.

Comment: It is a dataframe

Comment: So please paste again the `dput()` because something is missing like a `)` if I complete I get a list.

Comment: Ok, please see above

Comment: I have added a possible solution. Let me know if that is what you want :)

Comment: Don't mix base and ggplot graphics, IMHO that was the main error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution using `patchwork`:

```
library(patchwork)
library(tidyverse)
#Code
GraficosKMeans <- function(dados){ 
  g1 <- ggplot(dados, aes(x = cluster, y = ValorMedio))+
    geom_col()
  
  g2 <- ggplot(dados, aes(x = cluster, y = FrequenciaMedia))+
    geom_col()
  
  #Compose plot
  g3 <- g1|g2
  
  return(g3)
}

GraficosKMeans(dados)
```

[image]